# How to stop output of beyondcode/laravel-dump-server if server is not running

Tags: laravel, dump

In Laravel 6 backend rest api app I installed beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
with wrapper method for dump( and it works ok, when I run dump-server in console.
But if I closed console and do not remove dump( from my code I got errors in my app,
as data are still ouputted...
If these a way to check if dump-server is not runnig? In this case I would 
be eble not to run dump( in my wrapper function ...

Or somother tools with similar functionality ?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know too!